# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time Email-Listener

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to create a Python code for automatically listen any incoming email then download attachment of that email. I found [Email-Listener](https://pypi.org/project/email-listener/) library and practice the documentation. I'm using the exact code from the documentation. This is the code:

```
import email_listener

# Set your email, password, what folder you want to listen to, and where to save attachments
email = "example@gmail.com"
app_password = "password"
folder = "Inbox"
attachment_dir = "/path/to/attachments"
el = email_listener.EmailListener(email, app_password, folder, attachment_dir)

# Log into the IMAP server
el.login()

# Get the emails currently unread in the inbox
messages = el.scrape()
print(messages)

# Start listening to the inbox and timeout after an hour
timeout = 60
el.listen(timeout)
```

Well it works, when program running it will listen and download any attachment from unread email, either already exist on inbox or not. But after about 15+ minutes the program will stopped and display this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 20, in <module>
    el.listen(timeout)
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\email_listener\__init__.py", line 333, in listen
    self.__idle(process_func=process_func, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\email_listener\__init__.py", line 385, in __idle
    self.server.idle_done()
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 175, in wrapper
    return func(client, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 975, in idle_done
    return self._consume_until_tagged_response(self._idle_tag, "IDLE")
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 1596, in _consume_until_tagged_response
    line = self._imap._get_response()
  File "c:\users\0974\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1047, in _get_response
    resp = self._get_line()
  File "c:\users\0974\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1149, in _get_line
    line = self.readline()
  File "D:\PreProject\email_auto\emailauto_env\lib\site-packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 59, in readline
    return self.file.readline()
  File "c:\users\0974\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\0974\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\0974\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Is there any solutions? And I don't mind if the solutions use other methods, like not using `Email-Listener` library

Comment: Maybe your server or some network gear as a 15-minute no activity timeout.  The answer, of course, is to catch the exception and create the connection all over again.

Comment: Is there any chance the timeout problem is from IMAP server?

Comment: Sure, but how does it help you to know that?  You still have to recover from it.

Comment: Yeah you right. Anyway thanks for your help. I already use the exception but I'm still curious. So I asked my friend to run the code on his place and no error shows up. Seems my network is the problem